# call a pointer function in class

Tags: c++, function, pointers

I've a pointer function in a class that is defined outside the class and used as a callback.

The class goes like this

```
class A
{
    void CreateGrid(OWindow *win,int x,int y);
    Otkobject *GetIcon(void *data,Otkobject *obj,int x)
}
```

I've defined the `GetIcon` function like this

```
Otkobject *A::GetIcon(oid *data,Otkobject *obj,int x){
    //statements
}
```

For this I'm getting errors.

Then I tried

```
Otkobject A::*GetIcon(void *data,Otkobject *obj,int x){
    //statements
}
```

I'm getting function name and use callback. How to use this function pointer?

Comment: Could you tell us exactly what errors you are getting?

Comment: two things - what is the declaration of Otkobject, and are the `oid` in your definition and the missing semicolons in your class typos in your question, or in your code?

Comment: Add a semicolon at the end of your definition of `class A`. Your first try at defining `GetIcon` was correct except that you need to remove the semicolon and add a function body.

Comment: argurment of type Otkobject* (A::)(void *data,Otkobject *obj,int x )does not match Otkobject* (*)(void *data,Otkobject *obj,int x )

Comment: Also, are you talking about "function pointers" or functions that return pointers?

Comment: My previous answer was wrong. I thought you want the typedef of a member function. OK, your member function definition doesn't seem to go wrong. What's the error anyway?

Comment: this is the error i'm getting.argurment of type Otkobject* (A::)(void data,Otkobject *obj,int x )does not match Otkobject (*)(void *data,Otkobject *obj,int x ). I solved this error long back. but forgot what i did.

Comment: What's with all the down-votes? From the FAQ..."Downvoting should be reserved for `extreme cases`. It's not meant as a substitute for communication and editing."

Comment: Do you need a global callback function? Are you trying to use the callback function outside the class as a global callback function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a function returning a pointer, not a function pointer. The error might be the missing semicolon after the class declaration:

```
class A
{
    void CreateGrid(OWindow *win,int x,int y);
    Otkobject *GetIcon(void *data,Otkobject *obj,int x); // <- also here
}; // <- notice semicolon
```

Answer (score -2):

you should typedef the function. something like:
typedef Otkobject *function_type(void *data,Otkobject *obj,int x);

and then you can use the function pointer where ever you want

Comment: Can you explain a little bit.

Comment: Wrong answer. That's a member function, not a global function.